# How to target only the current hovered element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out how to target an element when hovered but the thing is it shares same class with other element on the page.

Here is what i'm doing... i'm working on a wooccomerce page in which i setting the entry_title class to `nowrap`, so that long titles can be on one line but i want to do it such a way that when user hover the product with long title, the full title appears (i.e add a class to the element and set `white-space: normal`)

Below is the CSS i'm using to make the title one line with ellipses

```
.woocommerce .product h4.entry-title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    transition: .3s;
}
.show_ftitle {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Then the jQuery is as follow

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wf-cell').hover(function() {
        $('.entry-title').addClass('show_ftitle');
    }, function() {
        $('.entry-title').removeClass('show_ftitle');
    });
});
```

Now the issue is that if i hover any of the product... the title of long product (in which i didn't hover) will show. only want it to work for the current hovered element. but i only have `class` to work with. Is there a way i can pin-point this and make it work only for the product that my cursor is hovered on.

Thanks

Comment: please share html as well

Comment: Why are you not just doing it in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `this` with a comma after the class. Example using your code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.wf-cell').hover(function() {
    $('.entry-title', this).addClass('show_ftitle');
}, function() {
    $('.entry-title', this).removeClass('show_ftitle');
});
```

});

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked!!... You're a life saver.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for JavaScript, just do it with css hover

```
.wf-cell:hover .entry-title {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Problem with your code is you are selecting all the elements, not the one you are using

```
$('.wf-cell').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.entry-title').addClass('show_ftitle');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.entry-title').addClass('show_ftitle');
});
```

Comment: Regarding the use of CSS, `show_ftitle` is not one of the class list, so it needs to be added, that is why i've to use Javascript

Comment: whoops, copy paste error, fixed it, should be using `entry-title` not `show_ftitle`